# Apache + PHP without ".php" File Extension but Including Path Info

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, pathinfo

I'm trying to figure out how to modify the .htaccess file so I can do two things:

1. Not have to include the .php extension on my PHP files (e.g., a request to `my.domain.com/page` maps to `my.domain.com/page.php`).
2. Do #1 while also including additional path info (e.g., a request to `my.domain.com/page/path/stuff/here` maps to `my.domain.com/page.php/path/stuff/here`).

I've found out how to do #1 by adding the following to the .htaccess file:

```
# Allow PHP files without ".php" extension.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

However, now I'd like to modify the RewriteRule so it works for #2.

Answer (score 1):

You could just try to use `Multiviews`, which is made to do exactly this:

```
Options +Multiviews
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, after searching for MultiViews, I found several articles warning against them (eh, to each his own), but that also led me to an answer that uses 2 rules instead of just 1:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\./]+)/(.*) /$1.php/$2 [L]
```

The first rule catches case #1 above, and the second rule catches case #2 above. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] #Remove the .php
```

Not sure what you want with the pathing stuff though.

Edit based off your comment, I've used something like this with php/angular. It's probably not "correct" or the best way to do it, but it worked for me.

**Htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine       on
# Allow the API to function as a Front Controller
RewriteRule         ^api/(.*)$ api/index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
# Allow Angular to have Pretty URL's
RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond         %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

**api/index.php**

```
// Pull the routing path
$router = explode('/', $_GET['rt']);

$version = $router[0];
$controller = $router[1];
$action = $router[2];

// Check for the file
if(file_exists($version . '/controllers/' . $controller .'.class.php')) {
    include $version . '/controllers/' . $controller .'.class.php';
} else {
    return false;
}

// Initialize and execute
$method = new $controller($action);
print $method->$action();
```

This lets me do something like: api/v1/users/login in the url, then will find the users.class.php file in the V1 folder, and run the function login.

Comment: It's the same as the OP has, except `NC,L`. Please always add explanation to your answer (what does `NC,L` mean?).

Comment: Kind of, but not really. The Regex's are different. Also: [L = Last](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) [NC = nocase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do it. But to answer jassok's question, it's a way to make an HTTP request more specific. You can grab the data from the pathinfo to determine exactly which function to execute, and therefore what data you expect in the query string or form data, and what content to return. That way you can write a single controller for multiple related requests.

Comment: I made some edits to the post, it sounds like you're thinking Front Controller? I could be completely wrong, but I edit my post to show something similar that Ive used in the past while messing around with AngularJS using a custom php controller.